# Get the return type of operators in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-keyword, return-type, type-traits

Consider the following function:

```
template<class T1, class T2, class T3 = /* SOMETHING */> 
T3 f(const T1& x, const T2& y);
```

I want `T3` to be equal to the return type of `T1+T2`. How to do that with C++11 ?

Note: I don't want the result of `std::common_type<T1, T2>::type`, I want real type of `T1+T2`, considering that the `operator+` can be a non-member function or can be a member function of `T1`.

Comment: Do you use `T3` in the function at all, or is it ok to remove the extra parameter and just make it the return type directly?

Comment: My point with that was that if you need `T3` again, you can use `decltype(std::declval<T1>() + std::declval<T2>())`.

Comment: @chris You should post your comment as answer. It avoids duplicated code if `T3` is required in the body of `f`.

Comment: @FrankS.Thomas, I would if that was the case (though it wouldn't be common), but I presume the accepted answer fit the needs well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The usual way is `decltype` and a trailing-return-type:

```
template<class T1, class T2> 
auto f(const T1& x, const T2& y) -> decltype(x+y);
```